# Use mongoid_slug with CanCan's load_and_authorize_resource

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3.1, mongoid, cancan

I'm using Rails 3.1.1 with cancan, Mongoid, and Mongoid_slug.

My model is using slugs, which seems to be working fine except when cancan tries to load the resource for the show/edit actions. Which results in this error.

```
Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound in PagesController#show

Document not found for class Page with id(s) test.

mongoid (2.3.4) lib/mongoid/criterion/inclusion.rb:151:in `block in execute_or_raise'
mongoid (2.3.4) lib/mongoid/criterion/inclusion.rb:149:in `tap'
mongoid (2.3.4) lib/mongoid/criterion/inclusion.rb:149:in `execute_or_raise'
mongoid (2.3.4) lib/mongoid/criterion/inclusion.rb:129:in `find'
mongoid (2.3.4) lib/mongoid/finders.rb:84:in `find'
cancan (1.6.7) lib/cancan/model_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:20:in `find'
cancan (1.6.7) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:110:in `find_resource'
cancan (1.6.7) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:68:in `load_resource_instance'
cancan (1.6.7) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:32:in `load_resource'
cancan (1.6.7) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:25:in `load_and_authorize_resource'
cancan (1.6.7) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:10:in `block in add_before_filter'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:421:in `_run__438852266152246612__process_action__2308888977565164453__callbacks'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:386:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:53:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:53:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:201:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:193:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:65:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:29:in `call'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:152:in `block in call'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:96:in `block in recognize'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:96:in `optimized_each'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:95:in `recognize'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:141:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:532:in `call'
mongoid (2.3.4) lib/rack/mongoid/middleware/identity_map.rb:33:in `block in call'
mongoid (2.3.4) lib/mongoid.rb:132:in `unit_of_work'
mongoid (2.3.4) lib/rack/mongoid/middleware/identity_map.rb:33:in `call'
warden (1.1.0) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.1.0) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.1.0) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.3.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.3.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:243:in `call'
rack (1.3.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:195:in `context'
rack (1.3.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:190:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:331:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:392:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:68:in `call'
rack (1.3.5) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:101:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47:in `call'
railties (3.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.3.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.3.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.3.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:53:in `call'
railties (3.1.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:456:in `call'
railties (3.1.1) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
```

Page Model

```
class Page
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::Slug

  field :title, type:String
  field :body, type:String

  belongs_to :user

  slug :title, :scope => :user

  validates :title, :presence => true
  validates :body, :presence => true
end
```

Controller

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def index
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @pages }
    end
  end

  def show
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @page }
    end
  end

  ...

end
```

Answer (score 2):

Another, possibily better way w/ CanCan is to use the :find_by option.

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource :find_by => :slug
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the query is looking for an document with id of 'test'. Are you sure the right paramaters are being passed into the show/edit methods?

It is probably an error in your view.

Comment: Mongoid_slug overrode the to_param method so the slug value 'test' was correctly being passed. But when CanCan tried to load the model with the find method, the model was still expecting to get the id, not the slug.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to override the Model's find method, as that's what CanCan is calling.

```
def self.find *args
  if args.length == 1 and not args[0].is_a? Symbol
    find_by_slug(*args) || super
  else
    super
  end
end
```